# NotImplementedError: pd.Grouper is currently not supported by Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I want to use `pd.Grouper` inside a Dask Dataframe but I get

> NotImplementedError: pd.Grouper is currently not supported by Dask

A sample dataframe:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

data_dict = {
    "FaturaTarih": {
        0: Timestamp("2021-10-04 00:00:00"),
        1: Timestamp("2021-12-18 00:00:00"),
        2: Timestamp("2021-10-09 00:00:00"),
        3: Timestamp("2021-12-18 00:00:00"),
        4: Timestamp("2021-12-26 00:00:00"),
    },
    "MüsteriNo": {0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4"},
    "SUBEADI": {0: "O", 1: "O", 2: "O", 3: "K", 4: "K"},
    "KATEGORIADI": {0: "SO", 1: "BU", 2: "RE", 3: "ÇİKOLATALAR", 4: "AT"},
    "MüsteriSınıf": {0: "LOK", 1: "LOK", 2: "LOK", 3: "KAFE", 4: "EGI"},
    "Adet": {0: 12.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 36.0, 4: 20.0},
    "NetTutar": {0: 9.38, 1: 13.52, 2: 17.5, 3: 102.6, 4: 29.6},
}

df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data_dict), npartitions=4)
# the line where the error raises
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['MüsteriNo', 'SUBEADI', 'KATEGORIADI', pd.Grouper(key='FaturaTarih', freq='M')])
                       [['Adet', 'NetTutar']].sum()).reset_index())
```

An answer to the issue [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1749) claims `pd.Grouper` is implemented but however I try to change the number of partitions or dtypes, the same error still raises. My question is basically how I can implement `pd.Grouper` or maybe another equivalent method in a Dask Dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

`pd.Grouper` is not supported in dask, as documented in [this PR](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/7857).

You can, however, group by using `df.FaturaTarih.dt.year` and `df.FaturaTarih.dt.month`, as shown in my code below:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {
    "FaturaTarih": {
        0: pd.Timestamp("2021-10-04 00:00:00"),
        1: pd.Timestamp("2021-12-18 00:00:00"),
        2: pd.Timestamp("2021-10-09 00:00:00"),
        3: pd.Timestamp("2021-12-18 00:00:00"),
        4: pd.Timestamp("2021-12-26 00:00:00"),
    },
    "MüsteriNo": {0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4"},
    "SUBEADI": {0: "O", 1: "O", 2: "O", 3: "K", 4: "K"},
    "KATEGORIADI": {0: "SO", 1: "BU", 2: "RE", 3: "ÇİKOLATALAR", 4: "AT"},
    "MüsteriSınıf": {0: "LOK", 1: "LOK", 2: "LOK", 3: "KAFE", 4: "EGI"},
    "Adet": {0: 12.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 36.0, 4: 20.0},
    "NetTutar": {0: 9.38, 1: 13.52, 2: 17.5, 3: 102.6, 4: 29.6},
}

df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data_dict), npartitions=4)

new_df = df.groupby(
    [
        df.FaturaTarih.dt.year,
        df.FaturaTarih.dt.month,
        "MüsteriNo",
        "SUBEADI",
        "KATEGORIADI",
    ]
)[
    ["Adet", "NetTutar"]
].sum()
```

**Output:**

```
                                                       Adet  NetTutar
FaturaTarih FaturaTarih MüsteriNo SUBEADI KATEGORIADI                
2021        10          0         O       SO           12.0      9.38
                        2         O       RE            1.0     17.50
            12          1         O       BU            1.0     13.52
                        3         K       ÇİKOLATALAR  36.0    102.60
                        4         K       AT           20.0     29.60
```